# У меня сегодня не подписывалось приложение ключом... Хочу поделиться!

Tags: android, android-studio, keytool

У меня сегодня не подписывалось приложение ключом... 
Что приводило к следующей ошибке на сервере (в Google Play Consol'e):

> Сбой при загрузке Загруженный файл APK подписан сертификатом,
>   отличающемся от указанного вами. Цифровой отпечаток вашего
>   сертификата:
>
> ...
>
> ...

Хочу поделиться решением проблемки!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оказалось, забыл алиас от правильного ключа.
В начале думал, что проблемы с выбором ключа...

Алиас к тому или иному ключу можно узнать с помощью команды (введенной в командной строке):

> keytool -v -list -keystore PATH\your_key.jks

Например,

```
keytool -v -list -keystore D:\YOUR_FOLDER\your_key.jks
```

(попросит пароль...)

После ввода 'вычисленного' алиаса все подписалось и опубликовалось нормально... )

P.S. Пользуясь случаем, хочу заметить, что от каждого приложения копии ключей целесообразно хранить на внешних носителях (лучше нескольких, потому что, если потеряется ключ, то приложение больше никогда нельзя будет обновить в Google Play Store)... и где-нибудь в тетрадочке записать какими ключами и алиасами подписывались приложения.

Это сообщение написал после того, как сайт попросил делиться личным опытом, что я и делаю с большим удовольствием! )

Answer (score 1):

alias также можно узнать, открыв jks файл своего приложения. он там явно указан среди прочих нечитаемых символов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, явно, это как?